# Apple CoreData Tutorial: What does 'moc = ...' mean?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In the tutorial on how to fetch data from core data, I found the following code.

What is this `...` operator?
What is this `moc`?

Am I supposed to implement some sort of protocol in order to have access to these special operators?

Thanks for any help
[image]

Comment: `moc` here is just a constant. `...` is nothing, or blank asking you to initialize the constant.... so put some code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"MOC" in CoreData refers to a [managed object context](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext).

> **Overview**
>
> A context consists of a group of related model objects that
>   represent an internally consistent view of one or more persistent
>   stores. Changes to managed objects are held in memory, in the
>   associated context, until that context is saved to one or more
>   persistent stores. A single managed object instance exists in one and
>   only one context, but multiple copies of an object can exist in
>   different contexts. Thus an object is unique to a particular context.

The `...` is not actual code, it's just representing that the initialization of the managed object context would go there.

For example:

```
let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

Comment: But why would they leave it empty in a tutorial?

Comment: @Koen Sometimes initializing the managed object context can be verbose so it was most likely to save space. I'm sure earlier in the tutorial they must have shown the initialization.